# Naming $V_{8n}=⟨a, b|a^{2n}=b^{4}=e, ba=a^{−1}b^{−1}, b^{−1}a=a^{−1}b⟩.$

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-presentation

**Introduction**

Many groups can be defined  by certain group presentation for example the  cyclic group , the group $\mathbb{Z}/ m\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$, the dihedral group $\ldots$ etc (see wikipedia page [presentation of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)).

**Question ?**

There is a group that is definied as follows,
$$V_{8n}=⟨a, b|a^{ 2n} = b^{ 4} = e, ba = a^{ −1} b ^{ −1} , b^{ −1} a = a ^{ −1} b⟩.$$

Does anyone know the name of the above group ? (the $V_{8n}$ group).

**Example:** The group $D_n $ with presentation $⟨s, r|s^{ 2 } = r^{ n} = e, sr = r^{ −1} s⟩$ is called the dihedral group.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am afraid you group is pretty trivial since $b^{-1} a = a^{-1} b$ we have $b^{-1} a = e$ and as such $b = a$

Comment: @the_architect: $b^{-1}a = a^{-1}b$ is equivalent to $(b^{-1}a)^2 = e$, not to $b^{-1}a = e$

Comment: Where does this group come up?

Comment: @MichaelBurr In the following article (section 4): http://www.quasigroups.eu/contents/download/2016/24_03.pdf  and in several other articles

Comment: I don't think these groups have a common name in general. Even for $n=2$, this is SmallGroup(16,3), which is somewhat famous for not having a really nice name. They still have some nice structural property (for example, $b^2$ is central, $\langle a_2\rangle$ is normal, etc...)

Comment: @verret Thanks !

Comment: With GAP  I always  obtain the semidirect product $(C_{2n} \times C_2) \rtimes C_2$; If you can consider that a "name".

Comment: @verret: I've been trying to prove thatt $a$ and $b^2$ commute, how do you prove that?

Comment: $a^{-1}b^2a=(a^{-1}b)(ba)=b^{-1}aa^{-1}b^{-1}=b^{-2}=b^2$.

Comment: You can then easily show that $\langle a,b^2\rangle$ is an abelian normal subgroup of index $2$, and $ba$ is an element of order $2$ not contained in it, so you get a semi-direct product, as Marc said.

Comment: This is not the dicyclic group of order $4n$, but is pretty close to it! See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group).